# Android ROOM to persist complex objects

Tags: android, android-room

I have a JSON Response from RESTFUL API and I have mapped to POJO which I want to persist using ROOM. The POJO has List of objects and object class in turn has List of Business objects along with other Business objects, Can someone give me an example on how to map these entities and define DAO to query them. Any links, examples or Tutorials will be of great help. The POJO is as follows

```
public class A{

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;


    @SerializedName("list")
    @Expose
    private List<B> list = null;
}

public class B{

    @SerializedName("dt")
    @Expose
    private Integer dt;

    @SerializedName("weather")
    @Expose
    private List<C> c= null;

    public Integer getDt() {
        return dt;
    }

    public void setDt(Integer dt) {
        this.dt = dt;
    }

    public B  withDt(Integer dt) {
        this.dt = dt;
        return this;
    }

   public java.util.List<Weather> getWeather() {
        return weather;
    }

    public void setWeather(java.util.List<C> c) {
        this.c= c;
    }

    public WeatherList withWeather(java.util.List<C> c) {
        this.c= c;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, can you share the sample project you have completed? There are some places I need to examine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use TypeConverter

Create a class that all you want to convert

```
class Converters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun gsonToWeather(json: String?): Weather? {
        return Gson().fromJson(json, Weather.class);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun factWeatherToGson(weather: Weather): String? {
        return Gson().toJson(weather);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun gsonToB(json: String?): B? {
        return Gson().fromJson(json, B.class);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun bToGson(b: B): String? {
        return Gson().toJson(b);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun gsonToC(json: String?): C? {
        return Gson().fromJson(json, C.class);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun cToGson(c: C): String? {
        return Gson().toJson(c);
    } 
}
```

Then on your database.

```
@TypeConverters(Converters.class)
abstract class YourDatabase {

}
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data

Comment: If we use Type converters the data will be stored as a single column in table, but I need to query the attributes of Business Object i.e. List<Obj>, How do we handle this. If we have to establish any foreign key constraints. If so, Please provide links for tutorials or any documentation.

Comment: Thank you the answer helped me a lot and Resolved the issue.